# How to sort a list with the scores in sorted set

Tags: sorting, redis

I want to sort a list with scores in a sorted set. I also want to use limit command.

I created a list and a sorted set like below.

```
zadd weights 10 apple 20 grape 30 banana 40 strawberry 50 melon
lpush list apple melon strawberry banana
```

I thought of sort command and tried like below.

```
sort list by weights limit 2 2
sort list by weights->* limit 2 2
```

I expected that list had sorted into "apple banana strawberry melon" order and only "strawberry melon" is returned by limit command.
But both command above does not work. (instead I got one that alphabetically sorted)

How can I get the result I expect?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Redis doesn't work that way. According to the docs **Sorting By** works for sorting by external keys not by values inside the external key. To be more precise, When Redis does `sort list by weights_*` it checks for all the keys mathcing this pattern and compares them with the values in the list and returns you the sorted result.

Example:

```
lpush list apple melon strawberry banana
MSET  weights_apple 10 weights_grape 20 weights_banana 30 weights_strawberry 40 weights_melon 50
```

Now if you try sorting, result will be

```
127.0.0.1:6379> sort list by weight_*
1) "apple"
2) "banana"
3) "strawberry"
4) "melon"
```

As you can see sorting applies on external keys on weight_* pattern. Not within a single entity ( a hash or sorted set)

You can do the same with hashmap or sorted set but the comparison happens with keys matching a particular pattern and then a value inside that key. 
For example to achieve the same with a hashmap or sorted set you have to do something like this.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lpush list apple melon strawberry banana
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> hset weight_apple value 10
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset weight_grape value 20
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset weight_banana value 30
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset weight_strawberry value 40
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> hset weight_melon value 50
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> sort list by weights_*->weight
1) "apple"
2) "banana"
3) "melon"
4) "strawberry"
```

This works well if you have a data structure like storing all the info's of a gamer in a single hash and a set containing Ids of gamers. Now you want to sort them by their scores.

You can also use get command to get other associated values.